# How to modify htaccess file to load properly my assets resources using Laravel 5.7?

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, routes, laravel-5.7

I'm working with Laravel 5.7.

I have modified the .htaccess file to eliminate the public path of my application.

The problem is that now only assets are loaded from the pages that have a one level of path eg(http://localhost/myapp/home) and not in those with more than one level eg(http://localhost/myapp/home/example/example2).

I tried to use laravel's own functions like `asset()`, `URL::asset()` and also the `HTML::style()` helper, but none of them correctly loaded the assets.

Also, I have used several examples of .htacces files from previous projects and they have not worked either.

## This is the code of my .htaccess file, that only load one level routing assets

```
Options -MultiViews -Indexes

RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.css|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|robots\.txt)$[NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^(css|js|images)/(.*)$ public/$1/$2 [L,NC]
```

I would be grateful if any of you had this problem and has been able to solve it, could you give me a guide or help.

Greetings colleagues.

Comment: Please note that Laravel is not designed to be used this way. It is designed such that all of the application should be *outside* the webserver's content root, except for the `public` directory which should be the web root. In your example, the simplest way to do it is to move everything up one directory and rename `public` to `myapp`. Then you shouldn't need all that .htaccess stuff.

Comment: Ok, Then, as can be done when a deployment is made without having the public path? If you can not have a custom server and serving for laravel. That's why I laravel was used in this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not change any directory structure inside laravel or your `.htaccess` file. The way you should do it is to make a symbolic link between your `public` folder of the laravel project and the `public_html` folder in your server.
Revert all changes you made, and just link the two folders like usual.
For example:

```
ln -s ~/nameOfProject/public public_html
```

This way you keep your laravel project as it should be, and all functionality will remain the same. plus you get the benefit of working with git.

P.S

You will need SSH access, and yes this should work perfectly fine on "shared hosting server".

Comment: I have done roll back to the modified files, they have remained as it comes by default. But still continues without showing me the assets in the pages with one more level on the route.

I have opened the browser's javascript console and I can see that it can not find the file because it is looking for it in the path of that level (http://localhost/example/assets...) instead of the root path (http://localhost/assets...)

Comment: what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: What I need is that assets can be loaded from any route in my project, not only in the first level routes.